# Bold text with cvlanguage and cvcomputer in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, typography, bold

When I typeset

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\firstname{firstname}
\familyname{familyname}
\title{title}
\address{address1}{address2}
\mobile{mobile}
\email{email}

\begin{document}
\cvcomputer{LaTeX}{good}{}{}
\cvlanguage{English}{not good}{}{}
\end{document}
```

`not good` is typeset in bold, but `good` is not. How can I typeset `good` in bold as well?

Comment: That doesn't compile ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B - Sorry, edited it.

Comment: You are using the version from a template provider? Not the current one from CTAN, right?

Comment: @Johannes_B - What do you mean exactly? I just wrote my own `moderncv` document, rather than adapting an existing template.

Comment: Because i see "**good** and not good" with the current version and "good and **not good**"  with the older version still around on LaTeX templates. Please add `\listfiles` above documentclass and tell us which version you are using.

Comment: Sorry my fault, with the urrent version, none of them are bold.

Comment: Please be aware that updating from 2010 to 2015 will lead to *substantial* changes in packages and the format. If you are on a tight deadline, do not update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using an old version of `moderncv`. The current version uses `\name{Joe}{Doe}`, older versions do not use or know command `\name`. Please check the log file and tell us the used TeX distribution (including version number) and the version number of used class `moderncv`.

The current versions for MiKTeX is 2.9, for TeX Live 2015 and for `moderncv` 2.0.0.

To get the current versions please just update your TeX distribution and check afterwards, that all packages are up to date.

For more informations see for example question [installing vanilla TeX Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) 
or [update the TeX distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55459#55459).

To update only class `moderncv` see for example [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117518/update-a-package-after-tex-live-freeze).

Without knowing the exact versions nunmer of `moderncv` you are using just now it is not possible to help you.  One possibility for you is to check the examples which are supported with class `moderncv`.  Then use only the shown syntax in the examples, but that mean that the given advices for newer version can not work for you!

**UPDATE:**
I found a version 0.8 of `moderncv`, so I was able to check the code.

In version 0.8 of `moderncv` you can find the definitions for the two 
commands `\cvcomputer` and `\cvlanguage` in file `moderncv.cls`, 
lines 377 until 383:

```
% usage (inside 'language' cvsection environment): \cvlanguage{name}{level}{comment}
\newcommand*{\cvlanguage}[3]{%
  \cvline{#1}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.225\maincolumnwidth}\textbf{#2}\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.725\maincolumnwidth}\raggedleft\footnotesize\itshape #3\end{minipage}}}
  %                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^

% usage (inside 'computer skills' cvsection environment): \cvcomputer{category}{programs}{category}{programs}
\newcommand*{\cvcomputer}[4]{%
  \cvdoubleitem{#1}{\small#2}{#3}{\small#4}}
```

As you can see, in command `\cvlanguage`  you will find a `\textbf{#2}`, 
which causes the bold writing.

I think the best way for you is to define a new command `\mycvlanguage` without the bold writing.

Please run the following MWE on your system ( I can't, I have version 0.8 not installed):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\firstname{firstname}
\familyname{familyname}
\title{title}
\address{address1}{address2}
\mobile{mobile}
\email{email}

%define own command without bold writing (deleted \textbf{}):
\newcommand*{\mycvlanguage}[3]{%
  \cvline{#1}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.225\maincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.725\maincolumnwidth}\raggedleft\footnotesize\itshape #3\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
\cvcomputer{LaTeX}{good}{}{} % Good written in bold
\mycvlanguage{LaTeX}{good}{}{} % Good written not in bold
\cvlanguage{English}{not good}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And thanks everybody. I am quite new to this part of LaTeX.